# Devise with custom Mailer and Authentication_keys not sending password reset email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building an Rails 6 Ruby 2.7.1 App with Devise (latest version) and am using Postmark to deliver my transactional emails. I am also using a custom UserMailer to handle these transactions.

The problem I am encountering currently is: When submitting the password reset request form, on submit the form is submitted, however nothing happens! my rails log show it started, then a completed 200 ok, however there is no redirect, no flash messages, and no email sent.

My problem is the lack of information being provided. And I am not sure where to start! Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

here is what the rails server shows on form submit:

```
Started POST "/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-09 00:21:45 -0600
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"21CmF4UDTbI8V/yt3yLy++s5Q2S2mLjZsDyeuqOJU1Lq5y7CMaljHE4BMEyaHmF4/EEtFLDmqMym2FzWHMpA/w==", "remember"=>"true", "user"=>{"username"=>"the_donkey"}}
  Rendering users/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.3ms | Allocations: 932)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.erb (Duration: 9.6ms | Allocations: 4504)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (Duration: 14.9ms | Allocations: 7800)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 17)
  Rendered hal_marketing/hammer_marketing/global/_early_access.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 51)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 18.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms | Allocations: 24633)
```

My UserMailer looks like: (And FYI My confirmation mailer works just fine!)

```
require 'browser'

class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
    include PostmarkRails::TemplatedMailerMixin

  helper :application
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
    
    default from: 'xxx@xxx.com'
    default reply_to: 'xxx@xxx.com'

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        @user = record
        @token = token

        self.template_model = {
            username: @user.username.try(:titleize),
            action_url: confirmation_url(@user, confirmation_token: @token),
            login_url: new_user_session_url,
            username: @user.username.try(:downcase),
            live_chat_url: 'my discord server',
            support_email: 'xxx@xxx.com',
            help_url: hal_marketing_community_support_url
        }

        mail to: @user.email, postmark_template_alias: 'community_welcome'
    end

    def reset_user_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        browser = Browser.new
        @user = record
        @token = token

        self.template_model = {
            username: @user.username.try(:downcase),
            action_url: edit_user_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @token),
            operating_system: browser.platform.name.try(:titleize),
            browser_name: browser.name.try(:titleize),
            support_url: 'xxx@xxx.com',
        }

        mail to: @user.email, postmark_template_alias: 'community_password_reset'
    end
end
```

My user Model looks like so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :timeoutable, authentication_keys: [:username]
  
  before_validation :set_modules
  before_validation :parameterize_username

  validates :email, uniqueness: false
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, presence: true

  def will_save_change_to_email?
    false
  end

  def devise_mailer
    UserMailer
  end

  private

  def set_modules
    self.buy_sell_access = true
    self.forum_access = true
    self.load_board_demo_access = true
    self.loadze_access = false
    self.roadze_eld_access = false
    self.roadze_tms_access = false
    self.truck_gigs_access = true
  end

  def parameterize_username
    self.username = username.parameterize.underscore.try(:downcase)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, Do you think that the problem you are having is sending the email or the proper device email?

Comment: Turns out I had an issue on the mailer. I’m going to post the answer. Was very simple but I think with the amount of time I spent looking at it, I overlooked it